# how to get a link name when right-click on explorer with window shell

Tags: c++, windows, shell

I use the following code. I can get the filename of the link to the file, but I can not get link's name. Who can help me?

```
STDMETHODIMP CJhContextMenu::Initialize(LPCITEMIDLIST pidlFolder, LPDATAOBJECT pdtobj, HKEY hkeyProgID)
{
  HRESULT hr;
  UINT nFileCount;
  UINT nLen,nLen1;

  m_bFail = FALSE;
  FORMATETC fmt = {CF_HDROP, NULL, DVASPECT_CONTENT, -1, TYMED_HGLOBAL };
  STGMEDIUM sm = { TYMED_HGLOBAL };

  hr = pdtobj->GetData(&fmt, &sm);

  if (FAILED(hr))
  {
    m_bFail = TRUE;
    return hr;
  }
  nLen = DragQueryFileA((HDROP)sm.hGlobal, 0, szFileName, sizeof(char) * MAX_PATH);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question is a bit unclear at the moment. Could you clarify on what you expect to happen with your code, and what actually happens?

Comment: Are you asking how to get the name of the file where the shortcut is pointing to? or the file name of the link itself?

Comment: i want to know the file name of the link itself.